# How do I make requests on a service of type LoadBalancer in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to be able to make HTTP requests on the service. Let me know if I need to post more information. Thank you! I've tried to curl the cluster-IP:30480 and ens160-ip:30480 and neither work. How would I make a simple request to the service?

```
kubectl get services kong-admin

    NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kong-admin   LoadBalancer   10.107.174.32   <pending>     8001:30480/TCP   9d

kubectl describe svc kong-admin

Name:                        kong-admin
Namespace:                   default
Labels:                      <none>
Annotations:                 <none>
Selector:                    app=kong
Type:                        LoadBalancer
IP:                          10.107.174.32
Port:                        kong-admin  8001/TCP
TargetPort:                  8001/TCP
NodePort:                    kong-admin  30480/TCP
Endpoints:                   10.244.1.17:8001,10.244.2.18:8001,10.244.3.16:8001
Session Affinity:            None
External Traffic Policy:     Cluster
LoadBalancer Source Ranges:  0.0.0.0/0
Events:                      <none>
```

Comment: your load balancer service is still in pending state, which means it is not exposed yet! are you using minikube or another kubernetes cluster?

Comment: You want to make HTTP request within the cluster or outside the cluster?

Comment: I would like to make http requests within the cluster

Comment: kubeadm using flannel @HichemBOUSSETTA

Comment: Then you can use service name to make HTTP request instead of cluster ip.

Comment: exactly, the service name serves as hostname within the cluster. kube-dns creates an internal dns entry for each service. in your case, (http://kong-admin)[http://kong-admin]

Comment: try http://kong-admin:8001

Comment: @Rajesh I must have misclicked the checkmark while looking at this yesterday. Sorry about that. I don't care about reputation on here. I've been a member for 8 years and have a low rep...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a service of type `LoadBalancer`. You can access it at `http://kong-admin`

If you just want the access from within the cluster, create a service of type `ClusterIP`